# Можно ли в gdb запустить функцию с правами владельца?

Tags: c++, linux, c, gdb

У файла есть suid, если я запускаю с нужными параметрами, то запускается bash от владельца файла, но если в gdb без параметров, просто меняю регистр и попадаю на эту функцию, то bash запускается от текущего пользователя, можно ли это как то обойти, чтобы запустить от владельца?

Comment: Чисто по логике — это должно быть строго запрещено, иначе это будет страшная уязвимость в системе безопасности (хакнуть sudo через gdb и т.п.)

Comment: Вам надо запустить сам gdb от этого владельца

Comment: Какой `bash`? Если вы о скриптах, то *suid* не имеет смысла.